# TimerEvent vs. ENTER_FRAME in AS3/Flex games?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, timer, flex4

I'm trying to write a simple game in AS3 / Flex 4, and I'm trying to find the best way from the get-go to handle timed execution of code.

The most natural approach would be to use a bunch of `Timer` objects throughout the program.  However that's supposedly pretty expensive on CPU cycles, compared to `ENTER_FRAME`.

However I'm not sure how natural it would be to base all of a program's timed execution off of `ENTER_FRAME`, and I have read on stackoverflow that it's got issues - that `Timer` doesn't - with regards to dragging down animation and framerate when the complexity of the program increases.

Another option that comes to mind is to simply use one `Timer` object in the program, whose event handler will go through and check on everything in one go around - kind of like blending the usual `Timer` and `ENTER_FRAME` approaches.

My question is this: What's really kind of the best idea for a video game in AS3/Flex 4, and why?  Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, the best way is to use one main Timer or ENTER_FRAME. Then inside that timer just call update function of each object you have in the game that needs time. Timer is probably your best bet.

Comment: Here's a decent article on the subject in regards to use of Timers - http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=910  -- I have personally used both, and can't say that either approach has had a significant impact. I tend to use an ENTER_FRAME and calculate the time between frames for movement calculations and update all objects. I'd go into more detail, but there truly is a wealth of information already on the internets in regards to this debate, just a google away.

Comment: It's hard for me to tell from reading if there's really any particular advantage to using either ENTER_FRAME or a single Timer.  It sounds like the idea of using several Timers is a bad one though.

Comment: Yes, I'd really focus on larger issues, like making your game. Switching from one to the other is really quite trivial, and as I've said I can't say that I have experienced a significant factor that made one or the other a clear choice. The article I posted was just so you were aware of the behavior of Timers, that is not what you might expect.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the one main advantage that I like about the ENTER_FRAME is that it's directly tied to the rendering process of the flash player. Whatever happens in your ENTER_FRAME handler is executed just before each frame render. With a Timer event, it is not guaranteed that you won't occasionally have your update executed twice in a given frame since your update and rendering are not in lockstep. Again, there is information on this subject out there.

Comment: @MartyWallace Just read your answer right now. There's also a wealth of information out there on the subject. Like yourself, I use ENTER_FRAME and if I want to run logic/movment/collision more often... I just do more iterations . You don't need a timer to be able to process those things more frequently than the framerate. I find that useful because I control when I want to run more iterations without having to change my timers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends entirely on *when* you want to update values, check collisions, manage input and so on vs when you want to actually *see something happen* on the screen.

- `ENTER_FRAME` will make your update logic and the rendering of your game *synchronous*.

  *Every time* an `ENTER_FRAME` event is dispatched, the scene is redrawn. What this means is that all your game update logic is *always immediately followed* by the screen being rendered. If the frame rate in your game drops due to complex graphics on the screen taking a long time to render, so will the rate at which your game updates. `ENTER_FRAME` dispatches are erratic, meaning they're not good for update tasks that you need to perform with even intervals between them.
- Timers will cause your update logic and the rendering of your game to become *asynchronous*.

  Timers can trigger far more or far less frequently than an `ENTER_FRAME` handler would. This means that your update loop could run multiple times before the scene is redrawn, or that the scene could be redrawn multiple times with no changes. Timers are less erratic than `ENTER_FRAME` handlers, making them better at doing something at set intervals. With that said though, there will still be a little bit of offset between updates:

  > Depending on the SWF file's framerate or the runtime environment (available memory and other factors), the runtime may dispatch events at slightly offset intervals. For example, if a SWF file is set to play at 10 frames per second (fps), which is 100 millisecond intervals, but your timer is set to fire an event at 80 milliseconds, the event will be dispatched close to the 100 millisecond interval. Memory-intensive scripts may also offset     the events.
  > - [help.adobe.com | flash.utils.Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

Personally I have always used `ENTER_FRAME` vs Timers. To me it is logical that if I make changes to the objects within a game, those changes should be immediately represented on-screen.

Timers are good if you want to be able to update components within your game faster than the frame-rate is able to manage. Timers are also good if you expect a given amount of updates to be completed within a certain timeframe, because they're not bound by the rate at which the screen is able to be redrawn like `ENTER_FRAME` is.

---

As for actual implementation, you preferably want to *pick one* and *implement one handler*. This means that you should only have a single function in the entire game that will be triggered by either a Timer or `ENTER_FRAME`. You do not want to be creating individual handlers in every single class that should be updated. Instead, you want to have your top level class (or a close relative of that class) define the handler. You also want to create a list within that class which will represent everything in the game that needs to be updated.

From there, you will create a small collection of methods that will deal with listing and de-listing updatable instances from that class. Each updatable instance will either implement an interface or extend a class that defines an `update()` method. It could look like this:

```
public interface IUpdatable
{
    function update();
}
```

From there, the update handler within the updater class will simply iterate over all of the updatables in the list and call their `update()` method, like this:

```
for each(var i:IUpdatable in updateList)
{
    i.update();
}
```

A final note is that this approach means that if you do decide to switch from using an `ENTER_FRAME` handler to a Timer or vice versa, it's a simple switch in the updater class and doesn't require you to change any other part of the game code. If you go around creating handlers in each class that needs to be updated, your change of heart will mean making changes to every single class.

Comment: With an ENTER_FRAME, you can still update your logic multiple times in a given frame by dividing the time delta and updating multiple iterations. And.. you still remain in lockstep with your render process.

Comment: @prototypical Sure, but that's still an intended batch of updates rather than an erratic collection of updates over a given amount of frames as with Timers.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you, are you saying that an erratic collection of of updates over a given amount of frames is preferable to intended batches of updates each frame ?

Comment: @prototypical No no, I'm saying that a single update in an enter frame handler is the same as knowingly triggering multiple updates per enter frame, but different to using a timer where multiple updates can occur out of sync from the screen rendering as an unintended event.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yep, just got your email, shot you one back.

Comment: A little-known fact about Timers is that they also fire erratically, since they have to yield to the "elastic racetrack." The closer your timer fires to a frame update, the more likely the event is to be fired at a different time than you expect.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship That's right, I didn't say they weren't erratic, in fact I quoted from the docs information about why they are still erratic.

Comment: Sorry, missed htat. But it bears repeating :)